# How to organize ASP.NET project to manage multiple views?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have three ASP.NET projects. They have same controllers & models and views are a bit different.

I set different views to customers as their requests but I want to integrate those projects into one.

Is there anyway to handle this problem easily?

There is a method to try. I can create sub folders on View and redirect to each subviews by instruction.

But I want to manage it easily. I want to create View1/View2/View3 and I would be able to indicate view on build step.

Thanks

Comment: how about turning the entire app apart from the views into a set, like nuget package? a homebrew "CMS."